# PHP foreach loop takes array elements out of numeric order?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array I am building like this:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    $this->_array[(int)$item->getPosition()] = $item;
}
```

When I then run through that array to output it, I expect this:

```
array (
    [0] => item0,
    [1] => item1,
    [2] => item2,
    [3] => item3,
)
```

But I get this:

```
array (
    [3] => item3,
    [0] => item0,
    [2] => item2,
    [1] => item1,
)
```

Which I can only assume is the order the keys were set in.  Why aren't they coming out in order?

Is there a way to force the array to order by keys in numeric order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `ksort()` the array first.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks.  Missed it when I went through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that the keys (`$item->getPosition()`) are being read from a database that doesn't respect their order. It's not a `foreach` problem.

1. Read the data
2. sort the array
3. output

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gary.

But you could also try sorting it in your database query. Assuming it's a MySQL Database:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` = 'value' ORDER BY `position` ASC"
```

That would sort them before they hit the foreach statement.